# Распространяются ли пространства имен в PHP на константы?

Tags: php

Распространяется ли пространство имен на константы?

У меня через define в двух разных пространствах (одно из них глобальное) имен объявлены одинаковые константы, на что я получил коллизию.

Код:

https://3v4l.org/2sdBS

Comment: казалось бы, сам спросил - сам ответил

Comment: Круто, вот только сам себе я ответ не дал.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/caein

Comment: Ок, а почему у меня одна константа была объявлена в Global. Я создаю Namespace, точно такое же имя константы, но другое значение. В этом же namespace ее вызываю, конечно, без указания namespace, и с удивлением получаю значения из первой, глобальной константы.

Comment: Эм, думаешь телепаты вышли из отпуска и видят твой код?

Comment: Черт. Тут код в 3 репозиториях из плагинов для Wordpress. Боюсь, если приложу - в своей жизни отпуск я уже не увижу)

Comment: Господа, такой код: https://3v4l.org/2sdBS

Comment: Потому что надо указывать неймспейс https://3v4l.org/Kbvh4

Comment: Это особенность define, ведь с const работает, верно?